# priority in getting the lock in pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading

Let say i have a list `List` and i have `pthread_t t1` that polls from the list and i have many other pthreads that insert elements to the list.
The list is locked with a lock `listLock`.
when `t1` has the lock - if the list is empty he goes to sleep with `pthread_cond_wait(..)` and when a thread inserts to the list he signals him.

my question is: if `t1` is in wait state and there are many threads that are stuck in 
`pthread_mutex_lock(&listLock)`, when the lock will be unlocked, will `t1` have a priority to get the lock or will he "fight" the other threads to get the lock?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will fight, however it's a fair fight. All callers are put into a queue based on the order that they called the wait. It's completely deterministic.

However given the way that you're using things, you may possibly want to think about using a read/write lock. It allows *N* simultaneous readers, but anytime something tries to do a *write* it will lock everyone down until it's done.

Comment: Getting "...put into a queue based on the order that they called `wait`" is a textbook example of *non*-deterministic execution.

Comment: Ah yes, quite true. So the order that they're ADDED is non-deterministic, but the order in which they AQUIRE the lock after that is deterministic. In other words it's not like a lottery or something. Your thread WILL get control of the lock (worst case scenario it will have to wait for N-1 threads if there are N threads).

Comment: Note that another advantage of read-write locks is they tend to be designed to favor writers, which prevents the readers from acquiring the lock only to find there's no data to be read.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said, the threads will fairly fight for the mutex. However, you may control how fair is the scheduling of the threads by using threads attribute variables. The following two links you guide you in the advantages and drawbacks of using this mechanism.

[Thread Scheduling with pthreads under Linux and FreeBSD](http://www.icir.org/gregor/tools/pthread-scheduling.html)

[Basic Scheduling Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Scheduling-Functions.html#Basic-Scheduling-Functions)